# Publishing a Google Sheet cell to an HTML page

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to provide external websites that aren't controlled by me some information they need to publish such as live inventory data. I'd like to provide them some Javascript that they can put on their site that I can control via a Google Sheet.

Here's an example:

Google Sheet A - Column 1/Row 2 = 6

With this code I provide, the external web admin makes his page say:

"We currently have 6 cinnamon rolls available"

Then someone comes in and buys two rolls. I go to the Google Sheet and update Column 1/Row 2's cell to '4' and now that same page says:

"We currently have 4 cinnamon rolls available"

Essentially i'm trying to create a CMS controlled by Google Sheet cells. I've been scouring the web and can find some attempts made in 2011ish, but I'm hoping there is a way that is as easy as embedding a YouTube video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that is close enough to what I was trying to accomplish at the time, so I figured I'd share. Sheetrock is a Javascript library that allows you to use your Google Sheet like a database.

http://chriszarate.github.io/sheetrock/

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that's "as easy as embedding a youtube video". You need to have a server that scrapes the content of the sheet then publishes it back out.